# Time out 500 error on Edmx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, azure, timeout, edmx

I developed a website using Asp.Net MVC and Edmx database and I published this website on azure and my database is also on azure and I've a functionality on website that uploads excel record into database and that excel sheet contain almost 18000 records every time I upload that sheet it throw Timeout error after some time so what should I do.

[image]

Initially I was not using any command Timeout but after doing some research I'm using this in constructor

```
 public ProfessionalServicesEntities()
        : base("name=ProfessionalServicesEntities")
    {
        this.Database.CommandTimeout = 10000;
        //this.Database.CommandTimeout = 0; //I tried this too.

        //((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 3600;
    }
```

Here is the code of
function :-

```
 public void SaveEquipments(IEnumerable<EquipSampleEntity> collection)
    {
        using (ProfessionalServicesEntities db = new ProfessionalServicesEntities())
        {
            string modelXml = XmlSerialization.ListToXml(collection.Where(x=>x.Type == Model).ToList());
            string accessoryXml = XmlSerialization.ListToXml(collection.Where(x => x.Type == Accessory).ToList());
            db.ImportEquipmentFile(modelXml, accessoryXml);
        }
    }
```

here is context file code for SP:-

```
 public virtual int ImportEquipmentFile(string modelXml, string accessoryXml)
    {
        var modelXmlParameter = modelXml != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("ModelXml", modelXml) :
            new ObjectParameter("ModelXml", typeof(string));

        var accessoryXmlParameter = accessoryXml != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("AccessoryXml", accessoryXml) :
            new ObjectParameter("AccessoryXml", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("ImportEquipmentFile", modelXmlParameter, accessoryXmlParameter);
    }
```

Comment: increase the specified time for processing

Comment: @jamiedanq how?

Comment: Can you show code for file upload, web.config & data context you're using (if exist)? How many times elapsed before reaching timeout? Also I want to know if you're assigned some value to `ObjectContext.CommandTimeout`.

Comment: Is this running on **Azure app service** or a **IaaS VM**?

Comment: @KaushalKumarPanday Azure app service

Answer (score 0):

You may be processing the excel on upload itself and processing it row by row. You have two options, one is to schedule a background job to pickup the upload file and insert it to DB and complete the request.

Next option is to read the whole file in one go and do a single bulk insert into the DB.

Comment: Actually I'm passing xml to my stored procedure and it take xml as an parameter and then using openxml it insert's the data into DB.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many things that can cause this. In Azure App Service there is a Front-end which has a timeout of 240 seconds. If your application takes more time, then you might run into this. This could be one of the probable causes.

In order to understand what is happening. Enabled **Web Server Logging** and **Failed Request Tracing**.

[image: Diagnostic logs]

See this for how to proceed further: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log